# wget post data to a website form

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, cookies, wget

This is for windows (wget)

I am trying to post and it seems something is wrong in my post data.

I have replaced http://www.kijiji.ca with url (I cant post more than 2 link on that post)

```
wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies url

wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt url/h-alberta/9003

wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt url/p-select-category.html

wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt "url/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=227"
```

After this one, I take the tokenid and value then:

```
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt --post-data "ca.kijiji.xsrf.token=1405297603536.f83244330a53ab891017888e3a9449a4&postAdform.title=AAAAAAAAAA&postAdForm.description=AAAAAAAAAAA&postAdForm.locationId=1700199&postAdForm.mapAddress=H3P%202M3&postAdForm.email=AAA%40gmail.com&AdId=&submitType=saveAndCheckout" "url/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=227"
```

It does switch the location but it does not submit the form.

Anyone able to help on this issue please?

I have attached the source

http://pastebin.com/qGUG8XYz

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: removed PHP. (it was for the form usage.)

Answer (score 0):

I get an error 500 when posting the same data as you... It does not give much information but the data is probably wrong (or maybe the cookies data ?).

I suggest you open Firebug if you're using Firefox (or Developer Tools on Chrome) and go to the "Network" tab. Then, just post the form via your browser like a real human would and look at the data posted...

I've tried and I got something like :

```
ca.kijiji.xsrf.token=1405600105039.5fadf4b1b9d0466bb573f44a4290f2f5&uuid=&adId=&postAdForm.galleryImageIndex=&postAdForm.geocodeLat=47.5699075&postAdForm.geocodeLng=-52.695462899999995&categoryId=227&postAdForm.title=AAAAAAAAAA&postAdForm.description=AAAAAAAAAA&postAdForm.locationId=1700199&locationLevel0=1700199&postAdForm.mapAddress=St.+John%27s%2C+NL+A1A+1A1&file=&images=&postAdForm.youtubeVideoURL=&postAdForm.phoneNumber=&postAdForm.email=AAA%40gmail.com&featuresForm.topAdDuration=7&submitType=saveAndCheckout
```

Which is a little more complex.

Moreover, your request probably miss headers. Same as before, take a look at Firebug and then set the headers like this :

```
wget ... --header="Referer: http://www.kijiji.ca/p-post-ad.html?categoryId=227"
```

If you post exactly the same request with wget, there is no reason it would not work.

By the way, are you sure about the token value ?

Comment: Yes, token value is different each session. (that is why you have different token value)